# Android Studio design view invisible when using certain Material 3 components

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, material-components-android, material-design-3

Recently I started using Material 3 Design components in my app.

For some reason though, the design view goes invisible when using certain Material 3 components in my xml code.
As soon as I delete them from my xml code, the design view works again.

The weird thing though, is that they are being displayed correctly when I launch my app with the layout that contains the components.

The components that cause the design view to be invisible are e.g. TopAppBar, MaterialCardView & BottomAppBar.

This is how it looks when I launch the app:

[image: launched app]

And this is how my design view looks:

[image: invisible design view]

Clean project, rebuild project and invalidate caches didn't help.

Any ideas what causes this behaviour?

Edit: I found a solution. Downgrading from `com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0-rc01` to `com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0-rc01` fixed the issue.